# Flex Mobile - Open a file included in assets

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am having trouble opening a file in the assets folder in my flex mobile application any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var myFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory. ("@Embed('assets/file.txt')");
var myFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
myFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, glossaryFileOpened);
myFileStream.open(myFile, FileMode.READ);
```

Comment: I get the error message Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type flash.filesystem.File.

Comment: be sure to post this as a formal answer and accept it as such, then.  There may be time delays since you're new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed.

```
[Embed(source="assets/file.html", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]  
private var TextClass : Class;   
var getFile:String = new TextClass; 
StyleableTextField(TextArea.textDisplay).htmlText += getFile;
```